# perl : difference of 2 arrays of STRINGS

Tags: arrays, perl, dictionary

I wan to find difference of 2 arrays of STRINGS 
I am new to usage of GREP and MAP . So , I need a little guidance

here's what i want to do ...

```
my @array = (    
  'hello this is a text',
  'this is a cat',
  'this is a dog',
  'this is a person',
  'this is a computer',
  'this is a code',
  'this is an array',
  'this is an element',
  'this is a number'
);

my @array2 = (
 'hello this is a text',
 'this is a computer', 
 'this is an array',
);

my @output = (
  'this is a cat',
  'this is a dog',
  'this is a person',
  'this is a code',
  'this is an element',
  'this is a number'
);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a easy task using [Array::Utils](https://metacpan.org/pod/Array::Utils) CPAN module:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Array::Utils qw/array_minus/;

my @a = ( 
# the data ...
);

my @b = (
# the data ...
);

# get items from array @a that are not in array @b
my @minus = array_minus( @a, @b );
```

If you don't want to install that module, just copy / take a look the `array_minus` sub (it uses `map` and `grep`):

```
sub array_minus(\@\@) {
   my %e = map{ $_ => undef } @{$_[1]};
   return grep( ! exists( $e{$_} ), @{$_[0]} );
}
```